How to show all users processes using `top -m` command in Alpine Docker container?
I want to watching the processes RSS in alpine container, so I using top -m switch show memory mode. But it shown processes that is current user, not all users processes. Is this behavior by design or a bug? I know the ps command can achieve my goal, but I'm just curious about this behavior of busybox command top -m.
# 1. start container
docker run -it --rm --name top_cmd alpine:3.19.3 /bin/sh
# and run `top -m` in this container
top -m

# 2. attach top_cmd container using other user like guest
docker exec -it -uguest top_cmd /bin/sh
# and run `top -m` in this container at same time
top -m

# 3. run ps command in this container at same time
docker exec -it top_cmd ps
# output
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /bin/sh    ### first step process
   16 root      0:00 top -m     ### first step process
   18 guest     0:00 /bin/sh    ### second step process
   24 guest     0:00 top -m     ### second step process
   25 root      0:00 ps

# watch this 1 and 2 step top command output, 
# they are only showing current user processes, even root.

This question might require a lot of research, so I thank the responder in advance.

Do no post pictures. Copy the actual text and use the code blocks.

It is not clear from the picture, but are you looking at the same container in the terminals?  It would be beneficial if you could further explain your setup and remove the image (replace it with text copied from the terminal instead).

I'm guessing it has to do with namespaces. The /proc filesystem in the docker container is bind mounted somehow from the host, and it makes it so that root in the container can't see /proc/{pid}/smaps.  But I'm mainly just handwaving.

@Kusalananda clear my question.

I don't think you can do this without starting the container with --privileged.  However, I don't know the security implications of this or what this option actually does (it obviously removes some security features), so I'm not going to write an answer saying that you should do this.

@Kusalananda, I agree with your point about security.
I found that by default, the permissions for /proc/{PID}/smaps are indeed isolated in container, making it inaccessible(Permission denied), even for the root user. When I tried adding --privileged, the isolation was removed, and it indeed worked.

I tried htop again, and it can display similar memory information and show all processes without needing privileged flags. It probably doesn’t get its information from smaps. But why do containers isolate smaps? Maybe I should ask this question separately?

I think that is the same question as this anyway.

Why do containers isolate some internals from the rest of the physical host (and other containers)?  Because isolation/separation is one of the core reasons why containers were invented.

For containers, /proc/{PID} is already isolated. The issue is that the /proc/{PID}/smaps of a program run by a non-root user in the container cannot be accessed by the root user in the container. This seems unnecessary and differs from the behavior outside the container.
